# Error while doing the serial programming in raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

And my code is:

```
import serial
s="Hello"
a=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)
while True:
  a.write(s)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix this line:

```
a.write(s)
```

With:

```
a.write(s.encode())
```

Comment: But i dont want to encode it,i simply wants to transfer the pi data to my pc terminal

Comment: If it is Python 3 you have to encode strings as bytes because bytes is the only thing that can be transferred over the serial connection.